# What is the advantage of a views::filter vs an if-continue?

Tags: c++, loops, std-ranges

I've been using ranges for a while, and each time I use filtering I feel like it can be easily replaced with a plain old `if` and `continue` statement. Consider these snippets of code:

```
for (auto value : values | ranges::views::filtered([](auto value) { /* ... */ })) {
    // ... do something with value
}

for (auto value : values) {
    if (/* ... */) continue;
        // ... do something with value
}
```

To me the second option looks way more readable. Besides, the first option may potentially involve some additional call overhead. So what are the advantages of filtering? Are there some guidelines on when I should choose one or another?

Answer (score 3):

The first version is victim to C++'s awkward lambda syntax. If you already have a ready-made predicate or use a lambda library for short lambdas, plus a namespace alias, then it becomes much nicer to look at.

```
namespace srv = std::ranges::views;
for (auto const& value : values | srv::filter(&Widget::is_visible)) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, it has the advantage of being very clear in its intent, instead of just being a pattern like the early continue. You will likely get very similar assembly from the two versions in an optimized build.

Comment: Passing a pointer-to-member-function can be a performance loss because logically the `filter_view` will hold a member pointer that has to be indirected through on every iteration, which may be difficult to optimize out. To avoid the performance hit you would have to do something like `| srv::filter(std::bind_front<&Widget::is_visible>())`, or just use the lambda, where the member function is held in the type instead of at runtime. Here is an example of optimizations not being done: https://godbolt.org/z/YqbaefGoG (GCC also doesn't optimize it properly, ...

Comment: ... it notices `&Widget::is_visible` is a constant but does not inline `std::invoke(obj, pmf)` with `pmf = &Widget::is_visible` the same way as `obj.is_visible()`)

Answer (score 3):

This feels like an opinion-based question, but lemme give you the same perspective I give when asked this question in JavaScript or any other language with a collection/sequence manipulation library:

(almost) Everything you do with fancy views and ranges can be done via a call to `reduce` (which has many names in C++ [`std::ranges::fold_left` from C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left), [`std::reduce` from C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) and [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)).

Everything you can do with `reduce` can be done with a for-loop.

When you have a single operation, there's almost always an algorithm for it. If there isn't, you might write one yourself.

Things get more complex when you have multiple operations within your loop. In which case, ranges will usually become more readable, more declarative, and be clearer on its intent (i.e. self-documenting code).

I'll try to come up with an example that highlights this:

```
auto input = get_vector<int>();
std::vector<widget_type> output{};
output.reserve(input.size());

for (auto item : input) {
  if (item % 2 == 0) continue;

  auto widget = get_widget_by_index(item + 1);

  if (widget.hidden()) continue;

  output.emplace_back(std::move(widget));
}

output.shrink_to_fit();
```

can be easy to read, but compare it to this:

```
auto output = views::all(get_vector<int>()) // views::all is to allow the immediate use of temporaries without lifetime issues
| views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 != 0; })
| views::transform([](auto i) { return i + 1 })
| views::transform(&get_widget_by_index)
| views::filter(&widget_type::hidden)
| ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

I personally am not a fan of using views directly in the for-loop expression. I like to keep them separate as much as possible, so my loop still reads nice and clear. That is, if I still need one at all: sadly AFAIK there's no `std::ranges::for_each` that we can **pipe into**, which is a shame.

Comment: Not sure if your pipeline compiles. Views do not work with temporaries.

Comment: See [`std::ranges::owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view). Added `views::all` just in case.

Comment: ok, but I guess it is not a "view" in its typical sense. If it works with rvalues then it must behave eagerly and therefore can be easily outperformed with the `continue` statement.

Comment: It's basically a fancy wrapper around the container, you can also put your container in its own variable if you prefer it that way. Point is, it won't change much. And collection/sequence manipulation libraries don't behave eagerly that's their whole point.

Comment: @Kaiyakha the whole pipeline is consumed as part of the full expression, in the constructor of the vector. Have you measured the performance of them?

Comment: `std` containers are move-oprimized. `views::all` creates a refrence to `ranges::view` models and moves in `ranges::range` models otherwise. The behavior is almost always optimized( unless given an rvalue `std::array`, in which case every element is moved).

Answer (score 1):

The views allow you to abstract things clearly. And since they are lazily evaluated, you can pass around complete processing pipelines through views.
This is especially powerful when building generic functional blocks.

```
auto processingPipeline =
    std::ranges::views::transform([](auto&& v) { return std::forward< decltype(v) >(v).second; }) |
    std::ranges::views::filter([](const auto i) { return i & 1; });

std::map< int, int > myMap{ { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 } };

for (int i : myMap | processingPipeline) // iterate over all odd values in myMap
{
    // ...
}
```

Of course this is a simple example, and the views allow for all kinds of use cases:

- An object might hold a range and you want to apply a processing pipeline to it? Pass in the appropriate views (here you could imagine `object.process(processingPipeline);`)
- If your code can be generic, use ranges to allow the calling code to pass all sorts of things (here we could imagine `otherObject.doStuffOnIntRange(myMap | processingPipeline);`)

Now which is clearer or better looking is opinion-based. I tend to think that using `std::accumulate` or `ranges::views` is a bit overkill for very simple processing. But they do shine when you need the genericity.

After that, it takes some getting-used-to but in the end the range syntax is IMHO very readable and shows intent clearly.

Answer (score -2):

Second version (`continue`) is much easier to read, compatible with older c++ standards, and very close to the actual execution behind. First version will most likely be optimized to a very close binary code, but its syntax is in my opinion, overly complex and involves a lot of compile time optimizations of the template classes behind.

First version has zero advantages. Your thought is good, with recent c++ features people tend to overthink and bloat iterations.

**EDIT** : Comments pointed that I'm wrong about the temporary filtered list allocation. So both codes might produce the same exact instructions at the end. However, the arguments that second version is much simpler and readable as well as compatible with older c++ standards without drawbacks, still stand.

You also have a slightly different version:

```
for (auto value : values) {
    if (!...) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

I tend to prefer that one, because the control flow is more visually obvious than a `continue`. But that's a fully personal taste matter.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the filtered view builds a temporary filtered list. You are wrong.

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. There's no allocation of anything, including any "temporary filtered list". Also, "*the first version iterates the original list and the temporary filtered one.*" isn't true at all.

Comment: @SebastianRedl correct, filtered views work lazily and implement a pool model (as most other views). The behavior described in the answer is rather about actions I guess.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that "compatible with older C++ standards" may be a requirement in some cases, but should never be a consideration when it comes to deciding between two viable alternatives. In other words, either you can use C++20, in which case "compatible with C++17" is irrelevant, or you cannot use C++20, in which case there is no choice in the first place. The only situation where this is not the case is when you present the C++20-only code snippet as an argument for why you should upgrade your project to C++20.